# Missing operand after '00' operator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataview

I'm trying to filter a dataview using a DataView RowFilter. I want to filter out data based on two date values checked on one column:

```
Dim dtFuture As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 6, Today)
dv.RowFilter = "ValidUntil >" & dtFuture.ToString & "AND ValidUntil > " & Today.ToString
```

I am getting the error `Syntax error: Missing operand after '00' operator.`. Not sure whether I am doing it the right way.

Comment: Syntax error: Missing operand after '00' operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to wrap the dtFuture values in single quotes :

```
Dim dtFuture As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 6, Today)
dv.RowFilter = "ValidUntil >'" & dtFuture.ToString() & "' AND ValidUntil > '" & Today.ToString() & "'"
```

ToString should also have brackets, and you need a space before the AND.

Comment: This seems ok to me, but better use culture invariant DateTime format, see my answer below...

Comment: As eFloh mentions on another post, you can actually exclude the parentheses on any method that doesn't have an argument.  So you dont need to have .ToString().  .ToString is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat the ToString method should have parenthesis eg; dtFuture.ToString()

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't it possible in VB.NET to leave the parantheses out when there are no arguments to a function? Don't remember quite...

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the dtFuture as SQL Date instead of using culture dependant ToString (use "#mm/dd/yyyy#" format)